# is 55 minutes enough time to connect in Guadalajara from Mexico City to Sacramento,Ca?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, short-connections, mexico, gdl

I have a 55 minute layover in Guadalajara before my flight leaves to Sacramento? I am flying from Mexico City - Guadalajara - Sacramento.

I've spoken to the airline and they tell me it is a legal connection, but I am worried because I think that the flight might not get me there on time to make the connection. Any experiences?

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of a very common question on this site. If the airline sold you the ticket as one itinerary, in a single PNR, then they are stating that they intend to get you to your final destination regardless of what happens.

I'm not familiar with Guadalajara's airport, but it doesn't look that big or overwhelming online. As you are coming from a domestic destination and Mexico does not have preclearance facilities for flights to the US, I would think that 55 minutes would be plenty of time in case of normal operations. If your first flight is delayed and you miss your connection then the result depends greatly on how you purchased your ticket. If purchased as a single ticket (which sounds likely based on the way you describe the situation) then you will be rebooked on the next flight to your destination. If purchased separately then they may rebook you as a goodwill gesture but (perhaps more likely), you'll need to buy a new ticket out of pocket for the next flight.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no change of concourse, it’s perfectly fine.  Basically if your ticket is with the same airline it should not be a problem.  The concourses are very linear and easy to navigate, with large waiting halls where passengers embark and disembark.  If you need to go between concourses then budget 10-15mins walking at a brisk pace

Some plane stops or departs from a remote stand, and this can be a source of delays when deplaning and emplaning to wait for buses etc.  The stands aren’t that remote, maybe 100yards from the terminal building, so once you’re in a bus it’s pretty quick, but it’s a bigger hassle to snake your way back to the concourses.  If you miss the early buses, it can take up to 20mins from the opening of the airplane doors to reaching the terminal.